# Object refrence not set to an instance of an object error in Installer Class while accessing App.config file

Tags: c#, installation, app-config, setup-project, configurationmanager

I am trying to make a Setup installer by using Installer class to add custom functions.Now as per my requirement i want to access the App.config file of the application at the time of installation and add the Connection string into it and save it.

Here is my installer code..

```
string targetDirectory = Context.Parameters["targetdir"];
string param1 = Context.Parameters["Param1"];
string param2 = Context.Parameters["Param2"];
string param3 = Context.Parameters["Param3"];

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings["Param1"].Value = param1;
config.AppSettings.Settings["Param2"].Value = param2;
config.AppSettings.Settings["Param3"].Value = param3;

//Save only the modified section of the config
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

But as soon as my application reached this line ..

```
 Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

It is giving this error..

> Error 1001:object refrence not set to an instance of an object

Here is my App.Config file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Param1" value="" />
<add key="Param2" value="" />
<add key="Param3" value="" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance